roll convention on 1 week instrument on LIBOR curve
I am looking at an AUD LIBOR PROJ curve I want to bootstrap, the business day convention for LIBOR is MOD_FOLLOWING, which seems logical for +1M instrument, however for a 1 week instrument should that also apply?  or should it be FOLLOWING?
So if start date is Monday 23March, 1W later = Monday 30March, however (for arguments sake) 30Mar is a public holiday, should we roll forward and use the 1 April (a good business day) or roll back to 27 March?

No. Weekly tenor adjustments should use a "Following" convention. "Modified Following" is normally only used for monthly adjustments so that the number of months between dates is not unexpeceted.
